# "Direct" derivation of exponential form of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory

There is the identity
$$ \zeta(s) = \exp\left(\sum_{n=2}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)} n^{-s}  \right) $$ for $\Re(s)>1$. Apparently there are quite a few possibilities to derive this. I am out to "try to prove this identity directly, at the level of formal Dirichlet series, using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic of course." as is suggested [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/the-riemann-hypothesis-in-various-settings/).

Since the von-Mangoldt function $\Lambda$ is zero for all n except those which are powers of a prime, I start with 
$$ \exp\left(\sum_{n=2}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)} n^{-s}  \right) = \exp\left(\sum_{p,\alpha}\frac{\Lambda(p^\alpha)}{\log(p^\alpha)} (p^\alpha)^{-s}  \right) $$
$$ = \exp\left(\sum_{p,\alpha}\frac{1}{\alpha} p^{-\alpha s} \right) $$
$$ = \prod_{p}\exp \sum_{\alpha} \frac{1}{\alpha p^{\alpha s}}.$$ Thats about as far as I get.

(I hope that has not been asked, yet).

Comment: You've pulled out too much, write it as $$\prod_p \exp\Biggl( \sum_{\alpha} \dotsc\Biggr).$$

Comment: Does the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} z^k$ look familiar?

Comment: I suppose $\sum_n \frac{1}{nm^n}$ is something well known?

Comment: not exactly exp(z), but I suppose some log thing??

Comment: Got it! $\log(\frac{z}{z-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}z^k = \log\frac{z}{z-1}$, gives

$$ \prod_{p} \exp \sum_\alpha \frac{(p^{-s})^\alpha}{\alpha} = \prod_{p} \exp ( \log(\frac{p^{-s}}{p^{-s} - 1})) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \zeta(s).$$

Comment: Something is wrong here: $\frac{p^{-s}}{p^{-s}-1} = \frac{1}{1-p^s}$ and not $ \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$. Where is the error?